# Prevent Row Reorder on Row Click in DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am allowing re-ordering of rows in a table with server side data loading. I noticed that with row reordering enabled, just a click on a row without a drag triggers reorder event and also leading to ajax requests to the server.

Example of a click a row click leading to the row-reorder event can be found [here](https://www.gotbootstrap.com/themes/smartadmin/4.5.1/datatables_rowreorder.html).

I need a way in which the row-reorder event will be triggered only when a row has been dragged rather than a click on the row triggering the event. With server side ajax request, this will be undesirable if a click on the row always causes data to be reloaded from the server database.

Kindly assist.

Comment: I don't know how to do what you are asking. If there is a straightforward way, I am not aware of it. But you can at least constrain the click/drag event to only one small portion of your table (e.g. to a dedicated "drag handle" column): [`rowReorder.selector`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowReorder.selector). That may minimize (but not eliminate) unwanted ajax events.

Comment: Thanks James. I think the best approach for now is what you suggested which willl reduce unintended ajax requests.